# How to use aggregrate in mongodb for array element

Tags: mongodb

I have two collection `conversation` and `usercollection`

MongoDB format of
**conversation** looks

```
[
 {participants:["ram","shyam"], recentchat:"hello shyam"},

 {participants:["ram","hari"], recentchat:"namaste"},

 {participants:["jhon","raju"], recentchat:"what's up"}
]
```

Likewise **usercollection** looks

```
[
  {"name" : "shyam", "address":"Kathmandu"},

  {"name" : "hari", "address":"Dolakha"},  

  {"name:"jhon", "address":"Pokhara"},

]
```

**The assumption is**: 
   `Ram is the user and it needs to access all the conversation list`

I want to use `aggregate` method of mongodb for joining two collection and get the result in following format.

```
[
  {friend:{name:"shyam",address:"Kathmandu"}, recentchat:"hello shyam"},

  {friend:{name:"hari", address:"Dolakha"},recentchat:"namaste"}    
]
```

Comment: Are those result sets from `db.coll.find()`? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Comment: Sure thanks @MarkusWMahlberg. To be more clear first two json format are my dbcollection  "conversation" and "usercollection"  and the last one is my desired data. So I am not sure what sort of aggregrate query i need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 3.2+ then you can use  [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregator for that.

Example:

```
db.getCollection('conversation').aggregate([
    {$match: {"participants":"ram"}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "usercollection",
        localField: "participants",
        foreignField: "name",
        as: "friend"
    }},
    {$project: {"friend":1, "recentchat": 1, "_id":0}}
]);
```

I use:

- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) - for select the parent document.
- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) - for data collecting from `usercollection` collection
- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) - for definig which fields must be included into document

Answer (score 1):

Get the recent chat for particular user from **conversation** collection

```
var recentChat = db.conversation.find({participants:"shyam"}).sort({$natural:-1}).recentchat
```

Update recent chat for that user in **usercollection**

```
db.usercollection.update({name:"shyam"}, {$set:{ recentchat: recentChat }})
```

Comment: Thats correct @Astro but We maynot know who is the next participant of conversation it may be anyone.

Comment: can you post a sample doc from both of these collections?